# Get all points with integer coordinates inside the convex hull of a CGAL triangulation

Tags: cgal

Given a CGAL triangulation, I would like to find all points with integer coordinates inside its convex hull.

I know we can iterate through all integer points and find their locations by `locate()`. But that would not be efficient. Is there a way we can find points inside a triangle of the convex hull? Is that an effective way to get lattice points inside a given triangle (vertices are all on lattice points)?

Comment: What I mean "points inside a triangulation" are points not in the infinite face.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: your question is not clear at all. What is your input and what is the desired output?

Comment: I  hope the input is a triangle with given vertices coordinators and output the lattice points inside it.

Comment: Is that in 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the all the integer points inside the bounding box of the triangulation, and use `locate()` smartly. For a query to `locate()`, store the returned cell or face handle (I still do not know if your question is about 2D or 3D triangulations). Then, use that handle as the `hint` parameter of the `locate()` function. If your queries are close to each other, consecutive `locate()` will return very fast.

Answer (score 0):

A simple possibility is to compute the 3D Delaunay triangulation of your points, then for each finite tetrahedron in the Delaunay triangulation, you iterate on the integer points in the bounding box of the tetrahedron, and reject the ones that are outside the tetrahedron. Testing whether a point q belongs to a tetrahedron (p1,p2,p3,p4) can be done by testing the orient3d(q,pi,pj,pk) for each facet (i,j,k) of the tetrahedron.

A slightly more efficient possibility uses the Bresenham algorithm to directly generate the points in the tetrahedra with integer coordinates (it is more error prone and difficult to implement for a not-so-spectacular speed gain, I experimented both and I am now using the first solution). The second solution will be better if your grid size is very small as compared to the dimension of the tetrahedra.